# Upgrading SingleLiveEvent says override nothing in observer methods

Tags: android, events, overriding, android-livedata

I'm trying to upgrade the class SingleLiveEvent.kt from the next article, to the latest libraries for implementation:

[STAR-ZERO on Medium -> singleliveevent-livedata-with-multi-observers](https://star-zero.medium.com/singleliveevent-livedata-with-multi-observers-384e17c60a16)

Compiler says that the next methods "overrides nothing":

```
override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>)

override fun removeObserver(observer: Observer<T>)
```

I'm a bit lost with it, do someone know what changes in the latest versions?

CLASS:

```
import androidx.annotation.MainThread
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

    class SingleLiveEvent<T> : MutableLiveData<T>() {
    
        private val pending = AtomicBoolean(false)
        private val observers = mutableSetOf<Observer<T>>()
    
        private val internalObserver = Observer<T> { t ->
            if (pending.compareAndSet(true, false)) {
                observers.forEach { observer ->
                    observer.onChanged(t)
                }
            }
        }
    
        @MainThread
        override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<T>) {
            observers.add(observer)
    
            if (!hasObservers()) {
                super.observe(owner, internalObserver)
            }
        }
    
        override fun removeObservers(owner: LifecycleOwner) {
            observers.clear()
            super.removeObservers(owner)
        }
    
        override fun removeObserver(observer: Observer<T>) {
            observers.remove(observer)
            super.removeObserver(observer)
        }
    
        @MainThread
        override fun setValue(t: T?) {
            pending.set(true)
            super.setValue(t)
        }
    
        @MainThread
        fun call() {
            value = null
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite an old article and those methods changed in the meantime. You can either override the proper ones by your self with `Code` -> `Override Methods...` or just copy them from here:

```
override fun observe(owner: LifecycleOwner, observer: Observer<in T>) {
    super.observe(owner, observer)
}

override fun removeObserver(observer: Observer<in T>) {
    super.removeObserver(observer)
}
```

The difference is here: `observer: Observer<in T>`

Comment: This initialization is not valid: val event = SingleLiveEvent2<String>() ?

Comment: It's says I need to implement the next: private val _isConnectedLiveEvent: SingleLiveEvent<Boolean>()
        get() {
            TODO()
        }

Comment: Your class name is SingleLiveEvent not SingleLiveEvent2 - maybe that's why you can't initialize it